# How do I add a folder to favorites on wine windows explorer?

Tags: wine

When I'm looking for a file on a program launched by wine, I'm directed to windows virtual drive. Its annoying to surf until I access ubuntu home folder. However, there is a *Favorites* bar.

How to add an ubuntu/home folder to *Favorites* bar?

Answer (score 12):

Just add a symlink to `~/.wine/drive_c/users/<YOUR_USERNAME>/Favorites` and it will appear in Wine programs' file dialogs in the *Favorites section*.

To do this from a terminal (replace `~/Desktop/favorite_folder` with your desired path):

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/users/`whoami`/Favorites
ln -s ~/Desktop/favorite_folder .
```